# ffmpeg set padding with different top and bottom bar background colors

Tags: ffmpeg, colors, set, padding

Using this ffmpeg command to set the padding color:

```
pad="max(iw\,ih):ow:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black"
```

[image: I get this result with command]

but I want different color for top for example green
and for bottom I want to set blue color.

[image: Desired output is this]

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two pad filters,

`"pad=(iw+max(iw\,ih))/2:(ih+max(iw\,ih))/2:0:0:color=blue,pad=max(iw\,ih):ow:(ow-iw):(oh-ih):color=green"`

This will pad with green at the top or left, and blue at bottom or right.